# Deleting old large global_log files CSV, CMS & FRM without SUPER privilege

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I have an 12GB old log file `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.CSV` which I'd like to delete. I checked `my.conf` and `general_log = 0` now but it was enabled for most of 2016.

```
TRUNCATE table mysql.general_log.
```

Returns "1142 - DROP command denied to user"

Is it save to delete or truncate the CMS, CSV & FRM files manually or is there some easy way to reclaim this 12GB space without stopping my server? Can I give my database user super privileges via my SSH root user? I dont have the mySQL root password.

Comment: Are your general logs store in a table of a file? Check the variable `log_output ` If it is a file just login to the server and clean it by using `cat /dev/null > /var/lib/mysql/mysql/general_log.CSV`

Comment: Great yes `log_output =FILE`. Why are there 3 files in that case? I assumed the log was a table using the CSV storage engine when I saw those 3 file extensions.